# Python-Jira create issue giving Screen error

Tags: python, jira-rest-api, python-jira

I am using Jira library with Python to create Jira-issue but getting below error:

> jira.exceptions.JIRAError: JiraError HTTP 400
>
> text: Field 'Component/s' cannot be set. It is not on the appropriate screen, or unknown.
>
> url: http://jira.corp.inmobi.com/rest/api/2/issue
>
> response headers = {'X-AUSERNAME': 'noc', 'X-ASEN': 'SEN-2505611', 'X-Content-Type-Options': 'nosniff', 'Content-Encoding': 'gzip', 'Transfer-Encoding': 'chunked', 'X-Seraph-LoginReason': 'OK', 'Vary': 'User-Agent', 'X-AREQUESTID': '125x24693491x2', 'X-ASESSIONID': '1tjvpeo', 'Connection': 'close', 'Cache-Control': 'no-cache, no-store, no-transform', 'Date': 'Sun, 29 May 2016 02:05:05 GMT', 'Server': 'Apache-Coyote/1.1', 'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=UTF-8'}
>
> response text = {"errorMessages":[],"errors":{"Component/s":"Field 'Component/s' cannot be set. It is not on the appropriate screen, or unknown."}}

Could anyone please help me to sort out it?

Comment: Can you post the JSON you are sending?

Comment: from jira.client import JIRA  
   import cgi, cgitb

   options={'server': 'http://jira.server.com'}

   jira=JIRA(options,basic_auth=('username', 'Password'))


  root_dict = {

    'project' : { 'key': 'ABC' },
  
    'summary' : 'Test',

    'description' : 'Ignore this. will be deleted shortly',

    'issuetype' : { 'name' : 'Task' },

    'Component/s': [{'name' : "ABC"}],
   }

   my_issue= jira.create_issue(fields=root_dict)

Answer (score 1):

Jira is complaining about the unexpected backslash in `'Component\s'`.

Change it to:

`'components: [{'name' : "ABC"}]'`

and it should solve your issue (pun intended).

Comment: Thanks Bro..it resolved...But am still surprised as I tried the same one but it was not working ..Now it worked...Thanks a lot ..:)

Comment: @viveksinha no worries, feel free to accept my answer if it was the solution.